# .jar works on Windows and Linux but not OSX

Tags: java, macos

I recently made an application for a community I'm part of,
Because I run Windows and don't have access to other OSes at the moment,
I posted it saying it was untested on Linux & OSX and people have reported back that it runs fine on Linux and Windows but fails to even start on OSX, One person posted the output when they tried to run it and this is what they got:

```
ccemu.jar: line 1: PK: command not found
ccemu.jar: line 2:???@: command not found
ccemu.jar: line 3???@D?: command not found
ccemu.jar: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `('
ccemu.jar: line 4: `?|?META-INF/MANIFEST.MFM??? Ew??Q^(1j???M7W?ħ???<p??K7??s?1??o?9?ة?}?#???C??z^?Jᘰ?S?ݿ????~X???I??kb,??J1b??͘s??????m??=-_?)??PK'
```

Obviously I have no clue what any of those errors mean otherwise I wouldn't be here,
Hopefully someone can insight me.

Comment: @Tharwen You mean text encoding(UTF-8 etc) of the compiled classes?

Comment: I have no idea what might be causing it, but seeing that many unexpected characters usually means that either something's encrypted or something's encoded wrong.

Comment: @Tharwen Hmm well I haven't been encrypting anything, So unless something funky is going on with the encoding type idk, I'll try force compiling to UTF-8 and get them to test tomorrow. Until then I await any other ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that the person who was testing it tried to execute it by doing `chmod +x ccemu.jar; ./ccemu.jar`, which in the general case doesn't work.  That person should probably try calling `java -jar ccemu.jar` instead.

Comment: The `PK` is a good hint that this is what was done as it corresponds to at least some of the header of a `.jar` file

Comment: It seems like this could be the answer I've asked the person and will mark this correct when they answer me thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem with a Java application (trying it on OS X) and the problem was that in the script that runs the application, the classpath was separated with `;` instead of `:`.